# PHP Login form does not work, what can i do to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have the following two php scripts: 
config.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'mind3');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

and index.php, which contains the login script and form:

```
    <?php
require_once 'config.php';
$username=$password='';
$username_err=$password_err='';
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = 'Please enter an username!';
    } else{
    $password = trim($_POST['username']);  
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $pasword_err = "Please enter a password!";
    } else{
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        $param_username = $username;
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("location: welcome.php");

            } else{
            $username_err = 'Username/password is wrong!';
        }
        } else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } 
    mysqli_close($link);
} 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Log in</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo(!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that whenever I input the credentials I have in my database, it does not redirect me to welcome.php, and it also doesn't tell me that the password or username is wrong.But when i don't input username or password I do get "please enter username" or "please enter password".

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: At this point add comma instead of = username_err,password_err = “”;

Comment: `mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))` you have undefined `$link` variable. I guess you've meant `mysqli_prepare($db, $sql))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the value of $username correctly.

**Change:**

```
$password = trim($_POST['username']);
```

**To:**

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
```

$hashed_password has to have a value since it's needed in password_verify(). Used mysqli's bind_result and fetch methods to get the value needed.

**After:**

```
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
```

**Add:**

```
$hashed_password = "";
$username2 = "";

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username2, $hashed_password);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Added exit(); after header(..) redirect so no other codes will be executed after the redirect call.

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$username = $password = '';
$username_err = $password_err = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter an username!';
    }
    else {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    }

    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $pasword_err = "Please enter a password!";
    }
    else {
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)) {
        $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username = ?";

        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            $param_username = $username;
            if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $hashed_password = "";
                    $username2 = "";

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username2, $hashed_password);
                    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
                    if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                        mysqli_close($link);
                        header("location: welcome.php"); exit();

                    }
                    else{
                        $username_err = 'Username/password is wrong!';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the username to the `$password`variable instead of the `$username`variable.

```
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
  $username_err = 'Please enter an username!';
} else{
  $password = trim($_POST['username']);  
}
```

Just replace `$password =` with `$username =`...

Answer (score 0):

You got an error with your code in the second snippet in line 10.
Here is the snippet with fix, please check code comment for further info.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $username=$password='';
    $username_err=$password_err='';
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = 'Please enter an username!';
    } else{
    //you got error here (was $password)
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);  
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $pasword_err = "Please enter a password!";
    } else{
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
    $sql = "SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        $param_username = $username;
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("location: welcome.php");

            } else{
            $username_err = 'Username/password is wrong!';
        }
        } else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } 
    mysqli_close($link);
} 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Log in</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo(!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```